# Knock you or, Get you out

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to use:

> I'll get you out!  (I'll knock you out.)
>
> Ill knock you out!

A girl was being really rude to a girl after she was out and she said:

> Why did you knock/get me out?

What sounds better "knock/get"?

As in "Dodge ball".......  Where the members of the other team are eliminated..

Comment: Is this about a sports game? Which one? And can you it clearer who the various "she" refer to.

Comment: Unless you are talking about eliminating somebody from a game or competation, "knock somebody out" means "render them unconscious", usually by hitting them. I doubt if you mean that, do you?

Comment: No @ColinFine,  I mean eliminating someone.  So can "get someone out" Or "knock someone out" work?

Comment: It can be about any game where a person gets eliminated and "she" refers to a girl.  @mkennedy

Answer (score 1):

In a sports competition, to be "knocked out" usually means for the team or individual to be eliminated from the competition. It would be unusual to ask, "Why did you knock me out?" because that is the whole idea.

In the game of dodge ball, each player is eliminated from a game one at a time and as such it may be reasonable for one player to ask that question to another player. "Why did you knock me out of the game? I thought we were friends."

Care should be taken using the phrase, as in more common usage "knocked out" can mean to make someone unconscious. To be sure of not being misunderstood, "Why did you get me out?" would be clearer.

In the example given the speech is informal between two people who understand the context and therefore the listener understands the meaning of "knocked out" as meant by the speaker so all is good.

Comment: I am not an expert on the English language and have no formal qualifications in English. I offer my advice only as a native British English speaker. I believe the advice of an untrained English speaker can sometimes be beneficial.